# What does sh:1:start:not found mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, gtts

I am making a raspberry pi chatbot using google text to speech. Here is my code:

```
import os
from gtts import gTTS
import time

text_to_read = "Hello my name is Alex. What's your name? "


language = 'en'
slow_audio_speed = False
filename = '1.mp3'
filename2 = '2.mp3'
filename3 = '3.mp3'
filename4 = '4.mp3'
filename5 = '5.mp3'
filename6 = '6.mp3'
filename7 = '7.mp3'
filename8 = '8.mp3'
filename9 = '9.mp3'
filename10 = '10.mp3'
filename11 = '11.mp3'
filename12 = '12.mp3'


def reading_from_string():
    audio_created = gTTS(text=text_to_read, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created.save(filename)


    os.system(f'start {filename}')
def reading_from_string2():
    audio_created2 = gTTS(text=text_to_read2, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created2.save(filename2)

    os.system(f'start {filename2}')
def reading_from_string3():
    audio_created3 = gTTS(text=text_to_read3, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created3.save(filename3)

    os.system(f'start {filename3}')

def reading_from_string4():
    audio_created4 = gTTS(text=text_to_read4, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created4.save(filename4)

    os.system(f'start {filename4}')

def reading_from_string5():
    audio_created5 = gTTS(text=text_to_read5, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created5.save(filename5)

    os.system(f'start {filename5}')

def reading_from_string6():
    audio_created6 = gTTS(text=text_to_read6, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created6.save(filename6)

    os.system(f'start {filename6}')
def reading_from_string11():
    audio_created11 = gTTS(text=text_to_read11, lang=language,
                         slow=slow_audio_speed)
    audio_created11.save(filename11)

    os.system(f'start {filename11}')

def reading_from_string12():
audio_created12 = gTTS(text=text_to_read12, lang=language,
                     slow=slow_audio_speed)
audio_created12.save(filename12)

os.system(f'start {filename12}')

f=open('name.txt','r+')
x=f.read()
f.close()
answer = input (reading_from_string())
if answer == x :
    text_to_read11 = "Hello again"
    reading_from_string11()
    f=open('name.txt','r')
    g=f.read()
    text_to_read12 = g
    time.sleep(0.5)
    reading_from_string12()
    f.close()


else:
    name=answer
    f=open('name.txt', 'w')
    f.write(name)
    f.close()
    text_to_read2 = 'Hello'
    reading_from_string2()
    text_to_read3 = (name)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    reading_from_string3()
    text_to_read4= 'What do you like'
    text_to_read6 = input (reading_from_string4())
    y=open('likes.txt','w')
    x=text_to_read6
    y.write(x)
    y.close()
    text_to_read5 = 'storing memory'
    reading_from_string5()
    time.sleep(1)
    reading_from_string6()
```

By the way, it goes straight from text_to_read6 to text_to_read11 because I deleted an unnecessary chunk of code.

Here are the files it opens reads and writes in:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT1ry.png)

Here's the error the code produces (after it says none is where i input and when it says sh: 1: start: not found is where it should speak using the gTTS module which i installed using pip3 install gTTS)

```
sh: 1: start: not found
Nonearthur
sh: 1: start: not found
sh: 1: start: not found
sh: 1: start: not found
Nonephysics maths and piano
sh: 1: start: not found
sh: 1: start: not found
```

Do you know what is wrong and how i can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your calls to `os.system(f'start {filename12}')` - there is no command named `start` found.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I ran this code on my huawei laptop and it worked so what is wrong on my raspberry pi?

Comment: I'm guessing i haven't installed a package or something

Comment: I think i asked the question wrong and it should be what is wrong with this code or something

Comment: can anyone tell me the packages that you need to install for python gTTS and maybe i have forgotten one of them

Comment: `start` is a Windows (`cmd.exe`) call. It won't work under Linux. Instead, what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to play the sample locally?

Comment: Thank you i am trying to create a gtts chatbot like siri that says (using gtts) Hello my name is Alex what is your name? It stores it to a file and asks what you like. It stores this data in a file and then when you go again if it remembers your name it says Hello again (name) and (i am yet to code this bit) it will be able to start conversations using what you like as a general subject. But it just won't speak. (soon i will use pyAudio and speechRecognition for input instead of typing but that is irrelevent right now)

Comment: do you know how i can do this on raspberry pi?

Comment: is there a substitute for start?

Comment: oh by the way i'm using raspbian instead of linux

Comment: My question is related to what you task you want `start` to perform - if it's to play the downloaded file, you can use `omxplayer --no-keys <filename>` instead. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/ - raspbian is a distribution (variant) of Linux.

Comment: i want to play the mp3 file

Comment: I will tell you if it works

Comment: Yay it works thank you so much. I was surprised I got an answer so quickly it's very impressive. Thank you again and bye

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `start` not being a command on the operating system you're trying to run your script on. `start` is only available under `cmd.exe` on Windows.

On [raspbian you can use `omxplayer --no-keys <filename>` instead](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/audio/).